# Cyrillic to Latin converter - some characters are not recognized on some computers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macros in VBA for MS Word 2010. It converts Kazakh letters from cyrillic to latin letters (some with acutes). I'm using it by incorporating it (.docm file) that contains the module with my VBA code into MS Word's global template (normal.dotm). It works fine on my computer and a few others, but on some other computers it fails to convert some of the characters like "Ғ" or "Ң".

```
Sub KazLat()
'Replacing All Cyrillic Characters to Latin
Dim i As Integer
Dim sKaz As Variant
Dim sLat As Variant
Dim a As String    
Dim b As String    
a = "I" & ChrW(221)    
b = "i" & ChrW(253)    
Dim rDoc As Range    
Set rDoc = ActiveDocument.Range

'List of Cyrillic Characters    
sKaz = Array(an array of kazakh letters in cyrillic. I am not showing it here 
because it gets corrupted)    

'List of Latin Characters    
sLat = Array("A", "a", ChrW(193), ChrW(225), "B", "b", "V", "v", "G", "g", 
ChrW(500), ChrW(501), "D", "d", "E", "e", "Io", "io", "J", "j", "Z", "z", 
"I", "i", "I", "i", "K", "k", "Q", "q", "L", "l", "M", "m", "N", "n", 
ChrW(323), ChrW(324), "O", "o", ChrW(211), ChrW(243), "P", "p", "R", "r", 
"S", "s", "T", "t", ChrW(221), ChrW(253), "U", "u", ChrW(218), ChrW(250), 
"F", "f", "H", "h", "H", "h", "Ts", "ts", "Ch", "ch", "Sh", "sh", "Sh", "sh", 
"", "", "Y", "y", "I", "i", "", "", "E", "e", a, b, "Ia", "ia")    

'No screen update while code is running    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
With rDoc.Find    

'Replacing cyrillic characters to latin characters    
   .ClearFormatting    
   .Replacement.ClearFormatting    
   .Forward = True    
   .Wrap = wdFindStop    
   .MatchWildcards = False    
   .Format = True    
   .MatchCase = True    
For i = LBound(sKaz) To UBound(sLat)    
   .Text = sKaz(i)    
   .Replacement.Text = sLat(i)    
   .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll    
Next i    
End With    

'Updating screen    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Just need to know what I need to fix in the code so that it works on all computers with MS Word.

Comment: Make the line `sKaz = Array(ChrW(...), ChrW(...), ChrW(...), ...)` so that it doesn't contain any non-latin chars. Also the range `For i = LBound(sKaz) To UBound(sLat) ` set inconsistently.

Comment: Thank you! Now, with ChrW, should I use decimal or hexadecimal codes? Which is faster? Which is reliable?
In sLat array, should I use ChrW for all latin letters? Would that make the code run faster? And I don't understand what you meant by "the range ... set inconsistently". Also, does this code work for any fonts?

Comment: Inconsistently means that lower bound set by one array and upper bound by another. There is no need to use `ChrW()` for ASCII chars (codes from 32 to 127). Although you may use the arrays of char codes instead of chars. Actually no difference if you use decimal or heximal, since all such constants are coerced to Long or Integer intrinsic type while compilation.